# CSOM Search limit to single site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, csom, caml

How would I update the following CSOM search code to limit search scope to a single site in the SharePoint tenant:

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(spClientContext);
keywordQuery.QueryText = term;
keywordQuery.StartRow = page;
keywordQuery.RowLimit = pageSize;
keywordQuery.EnableStemming = true;
keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(spClientContext);
ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Currently it brings back results from all sites. Using CSOM MS SP Client v4.0.30319. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add path managed property in QueryText to search in a specific site. For example:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "test path:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test";
```